# Passage Scrambler

Tags: python, c++

I have a passage. Is there a way from which I could scramble the words from the passage?

Comment: What's a _passage_? Did you mean a _paragraph_?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First, create a list with all the words of the passage.
If you have the text in another file, use "readlines" and "for" to iterate over it.
Then, use something like:

```
import random
List_Of_Words = ["these","are","the","words"]
random.shuffle(List_Of_Words)
```

Hope this helps !